# What are the conventions to wrap a long generic type in Java?

Tags: java, coding-style

I've read some recommendations about Java generic types [from Oracle website's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) like using one letter for name and so.

But let's say I have 4 generic types in a method, which makes the code line really long and breaks [the 1997 (wow!) recommendation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) or keeping lines short. Then how should I break the generic types?

So far, we've talked about that with some coworkers, and we ended up on the following, but we would like to know if there are some wide-spread conventions for that

```
public static 
        <
                R extends SomeClassName,
                E1 extends Exception,
                E2 extends Exception,
                E3 extends Exception,
                E4 extends Exception
        > R themethodNameThatCanBeABitLong(
                final SomeParameterClass<R> param1,
                final Class<E1> clazzE1,
                final Class<E2> clazzE2,
                final Class<E3> clazzE3,
                final Class<E4> clazzE4
        ) throws 
                ExceptionA,
                ExceptionB,
                ExceptionC {
```

To clarify in case: we are **not** seeking for opinion based things, but we would like to know about wide-used conventions (like from Oracle, or from Apache) cover this case. If multiple conventions exists, show us all of them, even if they contradict each other.

Comment: for what are `clazzE1 - 4` used?

Comment: That doesn't really matter here (the same question about convention applies whatever the generic types are and would be used for) but it's some exceptions the method could throw

Comment: EIther your question is primarily opinion-based or you are asking for an off-site resource: in either case you are off topic. At first glance there is a major over-design here.

Comment: Are you sure that such a complicated method is necessary?

Comment: If you have a method, with 5 parameters, all of them generic, that can throw 3 set exceptions and 4 custom ones, then you should probably rethink your design. That method has way to much responsibility.

Comment: I suppose there will be no "_wide-used conventions ... cover this case_" as it has kind of [bad smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)

Comment: Then, to all, is there a convention that states how many generic types a method shouldn't exceed?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, no Java coding standards talk about a preferred way to write types with large numbers of type parameters, or even how many type parameters are recommended.

In the absence of standards, you need to strike a balance between your need to express your code, and the other people's need to be able to read it.  Talk to your co-workers / team members about it.  They are the ones who will be reading your code.

---

In my experience, if you try to get too elegant with generic types, you end up fighting the type system and the elegance turns into unwanted complexity.